# Remove duplicate columns in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I try to delete columns with duplicate data in pandas, for example, the following data(They have the same data but different column names)：

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'one': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'two': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], 'three': [1, 2, 3, 4]})
   one two  three
0    1   a      1
1    2   b      2
2    3   c      3
3    4   d      4
```

I hope to get this result：

```
  one two
0   1   a
1   2   b
2   3   c
3   4   d
```

The method I use now is：

```
df2 = df1.T.drop_duplicates().T
```

But this is too inefficient, is there a better way?

Hope to get your help, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to improve a little efficiency like this:

```
In [935]: df_int = df1.select_dtypes(include=['int'])
In [933]: df_other = df1.select_dtypes(exclude=['int'])

In [949]: if df_int.T.drop_duplicates().shape[0] == 1:
     ...:     res = pd.concat([df_int.iloc[:,0], df_other], axis=1)
     ...: 

In [950]: res
Out[950]: 
   one two
0    1   a
1    2   b
2    3   c
3    4   d
```

To remove `transpose` completely, you can do something like this:

```
In [995]: import numpy as np
In [997]: if (pd.DataFrame(np.diff(df_int.values)).sum() == 0).all():
     ...:     res = pd.concat([df_int.iloc[:,0], df_other], axis=1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help, this can improve efficiency, but the data I need to process is too large, and the transposition takes too much time. If possible, I hope not to use transpose.

Comment: I've updated my answer to not have `transpose` at all. Let me know if this helps you.